# Align radio buttons next to the label

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

Here is a link to the page:

[Webpage](http://jobrangers.com/en/cds/70e95343/1bee9027)

I am using the following CSS Style:

```
input[type="radio"]{
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Also, we are using the `Bootstrap Framework`.

For some reason, I cannot get the labels to align directly next to the radio button.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: You could wrap the text in a span and give the span the same line-height as the input's height

Comment: @Martijn can you provide an answer?

Comment: Please read [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I would consider changing the height of your radio input types so that they are not 48px in height. Might have to adjust line-height somewhere also.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a little work, but I believe it should be what you're looking for...

You'll need to wrap the text in `span` tags:

HTML

```
<label>
    <input type="radio">
    <span>Yes</span>
</label>
```

CSS (I've excluded your current styles to make my code easier to read)

```
label {
    display: table;
    float:left;
}

input,span{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Then you'll just have to add a `clear:left;` to the text below it.